# Cascading express framework server GET calls in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, udp, webstorm

I am new to node.js and express.I am creating 2 servers and want to call a get to server 2 on receiving a get on server 1 from a localhost.

The 2nd server on receiving a get from the 1st server will then pass a response back to the first server which will then pass on the obtained response back to the local host.

Is there any optimal way of doing this? Any tutorials on using express with node.js that I can refer?

Thanks.

Comment: You won't be able to do this over UDP, since HTTP is TCP only. Essentially, you'll want to make a request to server 2 within your route handler for server 1, and send the response of this request back to the client.

Comment: I didnt mean server-server communication via UDP. I have removed that line to remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

Your best reference would be the [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html). A barebones implementation of what you want, using [request](https://github.com/request/request) to make your HTTP request from server one to server two:

**Server 1:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const request = require('request');

app.get('/serverOne', (req, res, next) => {
  request('http://localhost:3001/serverTwo', (err, response, body) => {
    if (err) return next(err);

    res.send(body);
  });
})

app.listen(3000);
```

**Server 2:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/serverTwo', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello world');
})

app.listen(3001);
```

**Request:**

`GET http://localhost:3000/serverOne HTTP/1.1`

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html

hello world
```

Comment: Perfect.I can now build on it. PS: I also required a npm install request --save. Since this is my first node application. Thanks cejast :)